# tracking error state space, linear control example

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I am trying to understand a detail from an example, from the control textbook *Slotine and Li (1991) "Applied Nonlinear Control", Prentice-Hall*, Example 6.4, pag. 220 (hopefully there is not any typing error in the book). A linear system is given:

$$\eqalign{
   \left[ {\matrix{
   {{{\dot x}_1}}  \cr 
   {{{\dot x}_2}}  \cr 
 } } \right] =& \left[ {\matrix{
   {{x_2} + u}  \cr 
   u  \cr 
 } } \right]  \cr\\ 
   y =& {x_1} \cr} 
$$

where the output $y$ is desired to track $y_d$. Differentiating the output, an explicit relation between $y$ -output- and $u$ -control input- is obtained:

$$\dot y = {x_2} + u$$

Until here it is clear. Now, the authors choose a control law:

$$u =  - {x_2} + {{\dot y}_d} - (y - {y_d})$$

and say that this yield the tracking error equation:

$$\dot e + e = 0$$

with the $e$ being the tracking error, defined as $ e=y-y_{d} $ and the internal dynamics:
$${{\dot x}_2} + x_2=\dot {y_d} - e$$
... and the problem continues.

**My question is**: how does one define the control law $u =  - {x_2} + {{\dot y}_d} - (y - {y_d})$ ?? And how does this relate to the two following equations ($\dot e + e = 0$ and ${{\dot x}_2} + x_2 = \dot{y_d} - e$)?

Any *simple* clarifying answer is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure with the internal dynamics? In my version of the book it is $\dot x_2+x_2=\dot y_d-e$. And this is just the result when inserting $u$ in the second equation, as I would expect.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you, You are right. I have edited the question, as per your indication. I am still trying to understand how one gets the equation $ \dot {e}+ e =0 $...

Comment: Probably my question is, how is the choice of tje control law $u$ made? This seems to be arbitrary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, @MrYouMath gave already a detailed and correct expalanation. Here some more words on the tracking error dynamics:

The dynamic of the tracking error $e = y-y_d$ is what you specify, i.e., the desired dynamics of the plant output $y$ along the desired trajectory $y_d$. This specified error dynamics should be asymptotically stable, since it might desired that $e \to 0$, as $t\to \infty$ or $y\to y_d$, as $t\to \infty$.

Here it is chosen as the error differential equation:
\begin{align}
0 &=  \dot e  + e \\
& = \dot y-\dot y_d + y-y_d
\end{align}
which is asymptotically stable since it is Hurwitz (the corresponding characterisitic polynomial has an eigenvalue equals $-1$). 
Consequently, initial errors $e(t_0)$ tend to zero as time increases.

Now to obtain $0 =  \dot e  + e $ you simply choose $u$ in the equation
\begin{align}
\dot y = x_2 + u.
\end{align}
In the example, $x_2$ is compensated exactly, so you need just to add the remaining terms $(\dot y_d,y,y_d)$ to obtain the desired error dynamics, i.e.,

\begin{align}
u = -x_2 + \dot y_d -(y-  y_d)
\end{align}

It follows

\begin{align}
\dot y = x_2 - x_2 + \dot y_d -( y-  y_d) \Rightarrow e +\dot e = 0
\end{align}

In the design, the dynamics in $x_2$ is not considered, it remains the internal dynamics

\begin{align}
\dot x_2 &= u =  -x_2 + \dot y_d -(y-  y_d)\\
& \Rightarrow \dot x_2 +x_2 = \dot y_d - e
\end{align}

final remark:
Note that this dynamics must be stable for $e\equiv0$. This yields the zero dynamics $\dot x_2 = -x_2$ which is indeed asympt. stable.

Comment: Thank you Carlos, your answer really helps and is easier for me to comprehend, so I accept it. I think is that what I missed before is that, one _chooses_ to specify the error dynamics, which in the example is $\dot{e}+e=0$, this is just a _choice_, that is the main point, all else follows. I also thank MrYouMath for the effort and the correct answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that @MrYouMath choosed additionally a parameter $a_0$. With this you can place a desired eigenvalue ($\lambda=-a_0$) and therefore the convergence behavior of the error dynamics.

Comment: Thanks again, just a small question. Why would one want $\dot{e}+e=0$, rather than only $e=0$ ?

Comment: We want that $e=0$ is a stable equilibrium. Hence with the ODE $\dot e=-e$ we obtain $e=0$, $t\to\infty$

Comment: looking at this answer again, I miss the point on the last equation $\dot{x}_2+x_2 = \dot{y}_d - e$, if this dynamics must be stable for $e=0$, if I substitute $e=0$ in it, I get  $\dot{x}_2+x_2 = \dot{y}_d$ so how do I get from here to $\dot{x}_2=-x_2$? Is $\dot{y}_d$ considered constant? (probably, I am missing something in this step)

Comment: The zero dynamics is considered by definition with zero outputs and zero errors of the output.

Comment: You can set y and all its derivatives to zero.

Comment: ok thanks, so that implies $y_d=\dot{y}_d=0$

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume you want $y$ to follow a desired $y_\text{d}$ and if you want dynamics of the error to be of first order then you define

$$e = y-y_\text{d}.$$

Assume you want the following first order error dynamics (note that the relative degree of the system is also one)

$$\dot{e}+a_0e =0,$$

which is asymptotically stable for $a_0>0$. Now, simply plug in the definition of $e$ to obtain

$$\dot{y}-\dot{y}_\text{d}+a_0(y-y_\text{d})=0.$$

As we know $y = x_1$, we know that $\dot{y}=x_2+u$, hence

$$x_2+u-\dot{y}_\text{d}+a_0(x_1-y_\text{d})=0.$$

Now solve for $u$ to obtain

$$u= -x_2+\dot{y}_d-a_0(x_1-y_d).$$

Note that $x_1=y$ and this method requires that $y_\text{d}$ is at least continuously differentiable.